# Using a WiX Selection Tree control, when I select Feature 1, I want Feature 2 to be selected automatically

Tags: wix, windows-installer, conditional-statements, selected, treecontrol

I have three features in a Selection Tree control.  I would like Feature 2 and 3 to be independently selected and installed but if Feature 1 is selected to be installed I want Feature 2 to be automatically selected since Feature 1 depends on it.  When my Selection Tree is displayed I see:

```
[-] All Features
    [x] Feature 1 (requires Feature 2)
    [x] Feature 2        
    [x] Feature 3
```

Where [-] represents the icon for "Will be installed on local hard drive"
and [x] represents the icon for "Entire feature will be unavailable".

When I select Feature 1 to be installed I see:

```
[-] All Features
    [-] Feature 1 (requires Feature 2)
    [x] Feature 2
    [x] Feature 3
```

But when I select Feature 1, I want Feature 2 to be selected automatically so it would look like this:

```
[-] All Features
    [-] Feature 1 (requires Feature 2)
    [-] Feature 2
    [x] Feature 3
```

I don't want Feature 3 to be automatically selected since it is not required by Feature 1.  Is there a way to do this?  This seems like a simple problem but I could not find any documentation or examples on how to do this.  I have tried to use a condition within Feature2 like the following but the condition never gets tested since only Feature 1 was selected:

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="All Features" Display="expand" Level="1">
  <Feature Id="Feature1" ConfigurableDirectory="APPLICATIONFOLDER"
           Title="Feature 1 (requires Feature 2)" Level="2">
    <ComponentRef Id="file1.txt" />
  </Feature>
  <Feature Id="Feature2" ConfigurableDirectory="APPLICATIONFOLDER"
           Title="Feature 2" Level="2">
    <ComponentRef Id="file2.txt" />
    <Condition Level="1">MsiSelectionTreeSelectedFeature="Feature1"</Condition>
  </Feature>
  <Feature Id="Feature3" ConfigurableDirectory="APPLICATIONFOLDER"
           Title="Feature 3" Level="2">
    <ComponentRef Id="file3.txt" />
  </Feature>
</Feature>
```

If only Feature 1 is selected, is there a way to "tell it" to set the Level attribute of Feature2 to 1 so that Feature 2 in the Selection Tree displays the icon showing it will be installed also?  If trying to set the Level attribute of Feature2 is not the right approach, is there another method I can use to accomplish the behavior I desire?

Here is my full program if you want to try it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="41788c15-290e-426f-934e-e5b3bf875013" Name="WixUI_FeatureTree" 
           Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="WixUI_FeatureTree" 
           UpgradeCode="5f5d4f80-96f5-4060-a718-539b547d8a29">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />
        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
        <?define FeatureTree=1?>
    <UIRef Id="MyWixUI_FeatureTree" />

        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="WixUI_FeatureTree">
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

        <DirectoryRef Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER">
      <Component Id="file1.txt" Guid="FEBD6C0C-1BDF-413C-B7B1-A4E18AC7A6FA">
        <File Id="file1.txt" Source="file1.txt" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="file2.txt" Guid="FEBD6C0C-1BDF-413C-B7B1-A4E18AC7A6FB">
        <File Id="file2.txt" Source="file2.txt" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="file3.txt" Guid="FEBD6C0C-1BDF-413C-B7B1-A4E18AC7A6FC">
        <File Id="file3.txt" Source="file3.txt" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
      </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="All Features" Display="expand" Level="1">
      <Feature Id="Feature1" ConfigurableDirectory="APPLICATIONFOLDER"
               Title="Feature 1 (requires Feature 2)" Level="2">
        <ComponentRef Id="file1.txt" />
      </Feature>
      <Feature Id="Feature2" ConfigurableDirectory="APPLICATIONFOLDER"
               Title="Feature 2" Level="2">
        <ComponentRef Id="file2.txt" />
        <Condition Level="1">MsiSelectionTreeSelectedFeature="Feature1"</Condition>
      </Feature>
      <Feature Id="Feature3" ConfigurableDirectory="APPLICATIONFOLDER"
               Title="Feature 3" Level="2">
        <ComponentRef Id="file3.txt" />
      </Feature>
    </Feature>

  </Product>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Can you try putting a variable for level, that way you can use a custom action when you click the next button for example to check if feature 1 is selected then update feature 2 variable to the level you require?

Comment: Using a variable with a custom action is a great idea but I wanted feature 2 to be shown as selected in the UI before the next button is clicked.  I ended up creating my own dialog using my own checkboxes which gives me the ability to do what I want since it gives me total control of how the checkboxes appear before the next button is clicked.